# Moving every 5 cells to new column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been trying to find a solution for moving every 5 cells in a single column to a new adjacent column in Excel. I'm aware of https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3360-excel-transpose-every-5-rows.html but it doesn't solve my problem the way I'd like.

To Specify what I want to achieve - Lets say I have column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

In an Excel sheet. I'm not sure if it's called transposition cause on all solutions with this keyword data was set differently. What I'd need is:

```
1,6
2,7
3,8
4,9
5,10
```

Of course data I'm working on has many more lines and would need to span to more columns in intervals of 5. Any easy vba or formula to achieve it?

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Let's say the first data is in **A1:A10**, and the second data is in **B1:B5**, and there is **no more data** in column **A**. What's in **C1**, and what's in **B6**?

Comment: B6 in output should be always empty cause i need it to populate only 5 cells and repeat depending on number of data so C1:C5 would contain another column with data if our teoretical excell would be larger (had more values in original column A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would transform the first column block wise into columns with 5 rows each:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Transform()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = 6 To LastRow Step 5
            .Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=(iRow - 1) / 5).Resize(RowSize:=5).Value = .Range(.Cells(iRow, "A"), .Cells(iRow + 5, "A")).Value
        Next iRow

        'clear copied values
        .Range("A6", "A" & LastRow).Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So essentially:

```
=INDEX($A:$A;ROW(A1)+COLUMN(A1)*5-5)
```

placed in B2 and auto populated to down and right did the trick (all data is in column A)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ColumnToColumnsSetRows()

    Dim rng As Range, r As Long, c As Long, rws As Long, ncl As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1")   'Starting range
    r = rng.Row             'Row of starting range
    c = rng.Column          'Column of starting range

    rws = 5                 'Number of rows to use in each column
    ncl = 1                 'Number of steps to move sideways


    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(r, c).Offset(rws))
        Range(Cells(r, c).Offset(rws), Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)).Cut Cells(r, c).Offset(, ncl)
        c = c + ncl
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that row counting variables **must** be of type `Long` not `Double`!

Answer (score 0):

..An alternative, since my previous code affected content in columns below result

```
Sub ColumnToColumns_SetRows()
    Dim rng As Range, rws As Long, c As Long, prts As Long, i As Long

    rws = 5                                         'Number of rows to use in each column
    Set rng = Range("A1").Resize(rws)               'Starting range
    c = rng.Column                                  'Column of starting range
    prts = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp) / rws + 1 'Division in parts

    For i = 1 To prts
        rng.Offset(, i).Value = rng.Offset(rws * i).Value
    Next i

    Range(Cells(rws + 1, c), Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)).ClearContents

End Sub
```